# Why are Immutable classes not Sealed in C#

Tags: c#, immutability

I am asking the question regarding Immutable object pattern and implementing it. I am not talking about the existing classes in .Net library like String.

I understand that immutable objects are objects which once loaded cannot be modified by any external or internal component. What if I derive the immutable class as it is not a sealed class. Then assign the object to the base class, and call a method in the base class. I have effectively changed the state of the base immutable class as its state is that of the derived class object.

```
public class Person
{
    private readonly string name;

    public Person(string myName)
    {
        this.name = myName;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
    }

    public void DisplayName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Person's name is {0}", this.name));
    }
}

public class AnotherPerson : Person
{
    private string name1;

    public AnotherPerson (string myName) : base(myName)
    {
        this.name1 = myName;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person me = new Prasanth("MyName");
        me.DisplayName();
        me = new AnotherPerson("AnotherName"); ;
        me.DisplayName();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output :

Person's name is MyName

Person's name is AnotherName

Comment: You don't even need `AnotherPerson` here, you've just reassigned a reference, the original object was not mutated.

Comment: You didn't mutate anything. You created another object with different data.

Comment: First: Immutability is more a "good practice" than a language construct.
Second: you're re-assigning the variable "me".
Even if you used a sealed class the results would be the same.

Comment: The `DisplayName` property is not immutable, the string object that it originally *pointed to* is immutable

Comment: You might wanna check this link it proved helpful for me when i had my questions about immutable objects  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability/

Answer (score 5):

Let's forget about the flaws of your example (the comments already said it all) and answer your question: "why are Immutable classes not Sealed in C#."

The thing is, immutability isn't a feature of the C# language. Some languages support immutability as a feature (in which case your point would be valid), but C# doesn't. In the end, you're just **building an immutable class out of existing, all-purpose features**. And therefore, limitations can ensue.

Also, **immutability is a precaution, not a protection**. The point is to prevent anybody to change the data through "normal" means. If somebody really wants to change the data, they always can, for instance through reflection (or sub-classing, as you mentioned). But if a developer does that, then there's no way he's ignoring he's mutating data that is supposed to be read-only, and we can assume he has a good reason to do so. The point of immutability is to prevent the developer from unknowingly shooting himself in the foot, not to lock him down.

Comment: Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

You can only assign `readonly string name` once. I'm currently not sure if this only possible in the constructor.

You assign it in the first run  `"MyName"` and in the second run you assing `"AnotherName"` to a completly different object that you created with `new AnotherPerson(...)`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Person me = new Prasanth("MyName");
    me.DisplayName();
    // vvvvvv   here you lose the reference to the old object
    me = new AnotherPerson("AnotherName"); ;
    me.DisplayName();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I was thinking about this because i read that Immutable classes can be used for storing configuration data(web.config/app,config) . I usually use static fields for that purpose and was wondering how i could i apply immutable objects in that scenario. In case of configuration data , i shouldn't even let it be modified by anyone , its read once from config and thats it. So i believe my understanding was wrong and in my scenario i cannot apply the immutable object pattern as described in all the tutorials.